# Multiple controllers with one route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I have found a couple of questions similar but none with a defining answer.

I have a static controller which is rooted so that views can be shown like so:

```
mywebsite.com/admin
mywebsite.com/index
```

etc..

I have another controller called content_categories. I want to also display the category with the same rout such as

```
mywebsite.com/category-1
mywebsite.com/category-2
```

etc...

If I set the category rout like so:

```
match '/:id' => 'content_categories#show', via: 'get', as: 'category'
```

This overrides my routes for 'index' and 'admin'.

I thought of creating a separate action in the static controller and separate route for each category (only three I want to display really) and using render :template. This works but obviously creates duplicate URLS.

Any better ideas on how to do this?

Comment: How does the route for your static controller look like?

Comment: I actually also have a static modal so I use `match '/info/:id' => 'statics#show', via: 'get', as: 'static_info'` for my views from the model and then I have `match '/index', to: 'statics#index', as: 'static_index', via: :get` for index view and the same for match view

Comment: Putting the static routes *before* the category routes should fix it. Routes are matched in the order they are specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the route for your static controller, but I suspect that it is a similar route to the categories route. The problem is that both of them act like wildcards "eat" all other routes after them. `match '/:id'` will match everything, and so does your static route (probably).

One solution is to introduce constraints to one of the routes, and place it first.

This can be a regexp:

```
get '/:id', to: 'content_categories#show', constraints: { id: /category\-[0-9]+/ }

get '/:page_name', to: 'static#show'
```

You can also do more complex constraints by [creating a constraint object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

On the other hand, if you have static routes like this:

```
get "/admin", to: "static#admin"
```

Then you should be able to solve the problem by just placing these routes **before** the any wildcard routes.

Comment: Hey @jesper thanks. After all that I didn't quite think about their order! Thanks for the info on Regexp will be helpful in the future.

Comment: BTW: That regexp, what are the constraints saying. That is should contain the word category?

Comment: Exactly. The id has to start with `constraint-` and be followed by one or more digits. If the id doesn't match this, the router will try the next route.

Comment: I am guessing you mean `category-` but I get it! Thanks :)

Comment: One extra cheeky thing whilst on topic. Now that this category route is working. Categories have many articles and articles belong to one category. Whats the best way here to set the route for articles to include the category int he url? e.g. `mywebsite.com/category1/article1`. Don't worry if too much to ask! :)

Comment: I guess you could try placing `get '/:category_id/:article_id'` before the category route.